# could not resolve property Nhibernate alias

Tags: nhibernate-criteria

Have two classes. Books and Rating.

When user rates i am adding record to a Rating. Rating has a foreign key to Books.

Now, i want to calculate average of rating for the books using criteria language.

```
                     var bks = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Books), "b")
                            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("b.CategoryId", id))
                            .CreateAlias("b.Rating", "r")
                            .SetProjection(Projections.Avg("r.RatingOne"))
                            .List<Books>();
```

When i run this, it shows an error :

> could not resolve property: Rating of: Site.Models.Books